Grafana Prometheus Variable using multiple metrics
I am using Grafana with Data Source Prometheus.
I have 2 metrics which is working fine in table

webex_users{job="pushgateway"}
missed_webex_hosts{job="pushgateway"}

Both the metrics have a same column name - Company Site
Now I wanted to create Variables which it should be used to filter both the tables.
I am using Grafana V11


To select multiple metrics with a single query, Prometheus supports following syntax: {__name__=~"webex_users|missed_webex_hosts",job="pushgateway"}

Thank you so much, It is now working fine..

We can use this following Query in Classic Query in Grafana Variables to add all the value from 2 metrics using Prometheus Query.
label_values({__name__=~"webex_users|missed_webex_hosts", job="pushgateway"}, Company Site)

